# How to get the direction of relationship in Neo4J?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I need to find out all the related nodes from a given node. I also need to identify the direction, whether it is incoming or outgoing, plus the ID, labels on each related node. Following is the query I am trying out. Would it be effective query? Is there any other simpler way?

```
MATCH (o)<-[or]-(e)<-[ir]-(i) 
WHERE e.firstName='Sid' 
RETURN o,ID(o),TYPE(or),or,e,ID(e),TYPE(ir),ir,i,ID(i)
```

With above query I am able to identify `o` as outgoing node and `i` as incoming node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use Labels + Indexes to find your node
2. You already specify the direction in your pattern so you know between your nodes
3. in case you don't you can get the direction regarding a node with:

this statement:

```
MATCH (n:Foo)-[r]-(m) WHERE n.id = "bar"
RETURN n,m,type(r), (startNode(r) = n) as out_n
```